# server name doesn't work (django + nginx + gunicorn)

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

It's my first time to use django + nginx + gunicorn.  I can't make server_name work.  With the following configs, I am able to see django admin panel at localhost/admin. But should I be able to see admin panel when I access local-example/admin as well?

start my gunicorn

```
gunicorn web_wsgi_local:application
2012-10-14 19:45:50 [16532] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.14.6
2012-10-14 19:45:50 [16532] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (16532)
2012-10-14 19:45:50 [16532] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2012-10-14 19:45:50 [16533] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 16533
```

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /Users/ruixia/www/x/project/logs/nginx_access.log  main;
    error_log /Users/ruixia/www/x/project/logs/nginx_error.log debug;

    autoindex on;
    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;
    tcp_nodelay    off;

    gzip  on;

    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

sites-enabled/x config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name local-example;
    root /Users/ruixia/www/x/project;

    location /static/ {
        alias /Users/ruixia/www/x/project/static/;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /Users/ruixia/www/x/project/media/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 10;
        proxy_read_timeout 10;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

um... I solved it by adding local-example to /etc/hosts

Comment: I'm looking for a solution with a similar problem above. I can't access my django remotely within the network using ip address of webserver or hostname. I already added the webserver name in /etc/hosts. I added the port in my firewall to be open. Any pointers is really appreciated.